# Meta tag description does not get updated in Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am using liferay to develop website and for each page liferay page developed I have meta tag for description and keywords.

This SEO information I have put in SEO section of the page. 
The problem what I  get is that meta description is not saved.

HTML Title and Keywords are stored but Description information is lost and is not retained.
I googled for this issue and found it was an issue reported by many.

In one of the forums they had hooked seo.jsp page, I do not know how and where should I put this seo.jsp page and how it will help me to save description on the meta tag so that the information is not lost.

Comment: when you say that you found quite a lot of information already, it helps to link to it and relate to the fragments that match your situation. Anyway, I hope that Pankaj's answer does help.

Comment: @OlafKock : Hi Olaf. I deployed the hook in liferay given by Pankaj but still the description is not saved. Keywords are saved but only DEscription doesnt get saved.

Answer (score 0):

You can get hook to fix from [DOWNLOAD](http://www.miguelpau.es/documents/10831/353748/meta-description-fix-hook-6.2.0.1.war) link. Deploy this hook in your server, then it should work.

Comment: I had downloaded the hook from the same link before. There were errors showing in seo.jsp which I tied removing by including some imports and deployed the hook under tomcat but still the problem persistes. Description is not getting saved

Comment: can you deploy that hook without performing any modifications? ignore jsp error any way it will be placed under ROOT/WEB-INF/html/...

Comment: No changes. It still doesnt ssave description

Comment: I deployed the hook but still the description is not saved. I depolyed the hook without making any changes to the hook that I downloaded.